# how to exit a function in jquery when an error happens in jquery.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I'woul like to quit my function when an error happens in jquery ajax. for example: if i'm calling $.ajax with a function which has other instructions out of $.ajax and when it comes that my $.ajax call has an error, if i try to call return to end up the remaining instructions, those remaining instructions are executed.

So, what i want is to end the whole function from the erro $.ajax parameter.

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "home.aspx/ReturnInfoAge",
 data: "{'dD':'" + $('#dDate_wx').val() + "','dM':'" + $('#dMonth_wx').val() + "','dY':'" +   $('#dYear_wx').val() + "'}",
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
   success: function (msg) {
    if (msg.d === true) {
       prt.children('.tipCont').remove();
     } else {
       getTooltips(prt, 'criticalv', 'critical', msg.d);
        showMessagingTiming('warning', msg.d, 'Vérification de la date de naissance', null, 5000);
         return;
          }
    },
     error: function (errorMsg) {
       getTooltips(prt, 'criticalv', 'critical', "Veuillez bien saisir la date de naissance.");
      showMessagingTiming('warning', 'Veuillez vérifier: certains champs n\'ont pas les valeurs qu\'il faut.', 'Vérification des champs', null, 5000);
       return;
     }
 })
//other instructions
```

I just don't want, if an error happens in $.ajax error parameter to execute the other remaining instructions

Comment: That ajax function is asynchronous, so by the time you've returned anything from it, the rest of your function has probably long since been completed. You need to do the other stuff inside the success (done) handler.

Comment: You might want to have a look @ [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551175/how-to-cancel-abort-jquery-ajax-request)

Answer (score 2):

error and success callbacks are called asynchronously, so your 'other instructions' starts working before one of those callbacks are called. You should write 'other instructions' into success callback.

```
function containsAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "home.aspx/ReturnInfoAge",
        data: "{'dD':'" + $('#dDate_wx').val() + "','dM':'" + $('#dMonth_wx').val() + "','dY':'" +   $('#dYear_wx').val() + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg.d === true) {
                prt.children('.tipCont').remove();
            } else {
                getTooltips(prt, 'criticalv', 'critical', msg.d);
                showMessagingTiming('warning', msg.d, 'Vérification de la date de naissance', null, 5000);
            }
            //other instructions should be here.
        },
        error: function (errorMsg) {
            getTooltips(prt, 'criticalv', 'critical', "Veuillez bien saisir la date de naissance.");
            showMessagingTiming('warning', 'Veuillez vérifier: certains champs n\'ont pas les valeurs qu\'il faut.', 'Vérification des champs', null, 5000);
        }
    });
}
```

If you want to return something from containsAjax function, use callbacks:

```
function containsAjax(onsuccess, onfail) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "home.aspx/ReturnInfoAge",
        data: "{'dD':'" + $('#dDate_wx').val() + "','dM':'" + $('#dMonth_wx').val() + "','dY':'" +   $('#dYear_wx').val() + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg.d === true) {
                prt.children('.tipCont').remove();
            } else {
                getTooltips(prt, 'criticalv', 'critical', msg.d);
                showMessagingTiming('warning', msg.d, 'Vérification de la date de naissance', null, 5000);
            }
            //other instructions should be here.
            onsuccess(msg);
        },
        error: function (errorMsg) {
            getTooltips(prt, 'criticalv', 'critical', "Veuillez bien saisir la date de naissance.");
            showMessagingTiming('warning', 'Veuillez vérifier: certains champs n\'ont pas les valeurs qu\'il faut.', 'Vérification des champs', null, 5000);
            onfail(errorMsg);
        }
    });
}
```

And call it like that:

```
containsAjax(function(msg) {
    // success callback, returns 'msg'
}, function(errormsg) {
    // error callback, returns 'errormsg'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The jquery ajax method returns a XMLHttpRequest object. You can use this object to cancel or abort the request.

```
var xhr = null;

xhr = $.ajax({
    url : 'path/to/file?some-parameter',
    success : function(responseText) {
        // some DOM manipulation
    }
});

$(document).click(function() { xhr.abort() });
```

Answer (score 1):

If your function is called on some event then you can use the below statement to abort it. You can write this statement in the error block of your Ajax call.

```
...
 error: function (errorMsg) {
   event.preventDefault();
   getTooltips(prt, 'criticalv', 'critical', "Veuillez bien saisir la date de naissance.");
   showMessagingTiming('warning', 'Veuillez vérifier: certains champs n\'ont pas les valeurs qu\'il faut.', 'Vérification des champs', null, 5000);
   return;
 }
...
```

Comment: AJAX requests are asynchronous (hence the name), so in at least some cases the event will have already finished being handled when the `error` function is executed.

Answer (score 1):

try throw exception

```js
error: function(){
    //...
    throw new Exception('Ajax error description');
}
```

it will stop everything and also you will see it in debug console