# Stopping an $.ajax call on page unload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a procedure running on a timeout to load data in the background:

```
(function getSubPage() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (cnt++ < pagelist.length) {
            loadSubPage(pagelist[cnt]);
            getSubPage();
        }
    }, 500);
})();
```

In `loadSubPage()` I'm making `$.ajax()` calls:

```
function loadSubPage(page) {
    if (typeof(initSubPages[page]) === "undefined") {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Main/GetPageData',
            data: { page: page },
            success: function (returndata) {
                // ...
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Error retrieving page data.");
            }
        });
        initSubPages[page] = true;
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the `error` handler is being hit when the user navigates away if any ajax requests are open.  I'm trying to get around this by `.stop()`ing the requests on `window.onbeforeunload`, but I'm not sure what object to call `.stop()` on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery exposes the XMLHttpRequest object's abort method so you can call it and cancel the request. You would need to store the open request into a variable and call `abort()`.

```
activeRequest = $.ajax({...
```

and to stop it

```
activeRequest.abort()
```

Comment: I see. Since I'm running the timeout, I'll need a map to keep track of these objects.

Comment: how do you send the ajax call if its within a variable? activeRequest.send()??

Comment: I added my solution based on the feedback.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `$.ajax` returns `XMLHTTPRequestObject` which has `.abort` function. This function will halt the request before it completes.

```
var xhr = $.ajax({ /*...*/

..
..
/* Later somewhere you want to stop*/
xhr.abort();
```

**Read more:** [How to cancel/abort jQuery AJAX request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551175/how-to-cancel-abort-jquery-ajax-request)

Answer (score 0):

[Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

This should come in handy.. You have a jQuery method for doing just that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I used based on the feedback:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {            
    for (page in ajaxing) {
        if (ajaxing[page] != null)
            ajaxing[page].abort();
    }
};

var ajaxing = {};

function loadSubPage(page) {
    if (typeof(initSubPages[page]) === "undefined") {
        var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Main/GetPageData',
            data: { page: page },
            success: function (returndata) {
                 // ...
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Error retrieving page data.");
            },
            complete: function() {
                ajaxing[lot] = null;
            }
        });
        ajaxing[page] = ajaxRequest;
        initSubPages[page] = true;
    }
}
```