# How to kill the previous ajax request in server side?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, tomcat

I am using the **JQuery 1.9.1** . This question may be a possible duplicate of some previous questions.But those are out of date.So I need an upto date solution.

For my java application , I am sending a continuous request to the `tomcat server` for every `10 sec` through `JQuery-Ajax` to get the data like ,

```
function startPolling(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "My URL",
        dataType: "html",
        timeout: 10000,

        success: function(response) {                       
            if(response != null && response !="" && response !="null")
                $("#sucess").html(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            xhr.abort();
            //alert('Error: ' + e);
        },

        complete: function(xhr, status) {
            xhr.abort(); 
            startPolling();
        },
    });
}
```

Please make sure am I `abort/cancel` the `client side` previous request in proper manner.

Also how do I abort the `server side request processing` , Before sending the new request through ajax.

Hope our stack users will help me.

Comment: Simple answer you can't do it from client side.

Comment: @Arun I have seen your previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551175/how-to-cancel-abort-jquery-ajax-request/4551178 . But that was very old.

Comment: one possible way is the server to return a process reference id whenever a request is made then sent the process id back to the sever with a cancel request and in server side you need to apply some kind of cancel logic

Comment: That is the problem with `abort` even though you abort the request it affects only the client side, the server side processing will continue

Comment: @Arun Am I aborting the previous client side ajax request correctly using JQuery 1.9.1 ?

Comment: no there is a bug in the code

Comment: Try `var pollXhr;
function startPolling(){
    if(pollXhr){
        pollXhr.abort()
    }

    pollXhr = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "My URL",
        dataType: "html",
        timeout: 10000,

        success: function(response) {                       
            if(response != null && response !="" && response !="null")
                $("#sucess").html(response);
        },
        complete: function(xhr, status) {
            pollXhr = null;
            startPolling();
        },
    });
}`

Comment: Is this correct `xhr.ajaxStop();` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37499/discussion-between-kite-player-and-arun-p-johny)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the client side abort here

```
var pollXhr;
function startPolling(){
    if(pollXhr){
        pollXhr.abort()
    }

    pollXhr = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "My URL",
        dataType: "html",
        timeout: 10000,

        success: function(response) {                       
            if(response != null && response !="" && response !="null")
                $("#sucess").html(response);
        },
        complete: function(xhr, status) {
            pollXhr = null;
            startPolling();
        },
    });
}
```

Note: This will not stop the server side processing