# Stop previous ajax when new request is made

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a script

```
$('#postinput').on('keyup',function(){ 
    var txt=$(this).val();

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "action.php",
       data: 'txt='+txt,
       cache: false,
       context:this,
       success: function(html)
       {
           alert(html);
       }

   });

});
```

Suppose someone types a ,ajax runs . Immediately he types b c and so on. Ajax runs everytime. Is there a way to stop previous request when new is made ?

Comment: Why don't you start only one request after the last keystroke?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

Comment: @Andreas i was using loading image to show processing. `setTimeout` was giving me problem with loading image show n hide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Abort previous ajax request on new request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244341/abort-previous-ajax-request-on-new-request)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `abort()` method of the `xhr`. Try this:

```
var currentXhr;
$('#postinput').on('keyup',function(){ 
    currentXhr && currentXhr.readyState != 4 && currentXhr.abort(); // clear previous request

    var txt = $(this).val();
    var currentXhr = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "action.php",
        data: 'txt=' + txt,
        cache: false,
        context:this,
        success: function(html) {
            alert(html);
        }
    });
});
```

If you don't want to use a global variable, you could store the `xhr` in a `data-*` attribute of the `#postinput` element.

Another method is to only fire the AJAX request when the user has stopped typing:

```
var timer;
$('#postinput').on('keyup',function(){ 
    clearTimeout(timer);

    var txt = $(this).val();
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "action.php",
            data: 'txt=' + txt,
            cache: false,
            context:this,
            success: function(html) {
                alert(html);
            }
        });
    }, 100); // sends request 100ms after typing stops.
});
```

Comment: Hey tnx. I wanted to ask 2 things . Whatever im trying to do.. is it a wrong practice to stop ajax  ?  Suppose i'm using multiple ajax. the above code won't affect other ones ryt?

Comment: Stopping AJAX isn't a bad thing at all. I'd say it's a very good thing to stop AJAX requests which are out of date. By storing the reference you will only stop processing of that specific request, all others will be unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this with Jquery-

```
jaxRequests = new Array();

queueRequest = function(whatever, you, want) {
    if(ajaxRequests[ajaxRequests.length - 1]) {
        ajaxRequests[ajaxRequests.length - 1].abort();
    }

    ajaxRequests[ajaxRequests.length] = //Insert New jQuery AJAX call here.
}
```