# Manage multiple async functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

button1

```html
<button>button 1</button>
<button>button 2</button>
<button>button 3</button>
<button>button 4</button>
```

Let's say I have multiple button on a page. When you click on them they turn red. This transformation takes awhile (5-30 seconds).

I implemented an Ajax call that starts the transformation when a button is clicked, it turns the button into red when completed.  The button turns red only after the server has responded.

I'm trying to implement a mechanism for ensuring that only one transformation is processed at a time.  That is, if the user clicks multiple buttons there is only ever one Ajax call that is being processed at a given time.

I was thinking about implementing a Queue mechanism pushing the ajax call in an array when the user click on a button and run each one recursively. But I don't know how to do it dynamically, meaning, how to tell to my function: 'hey the user add a new item in the queue' please proceed.

I have to connect my array of ajax calls and my function that proceeds ajax calls once at a time. My function should listen to any events occurring in the array.

Any other idea?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say only one ajax call is processed at a time, does that mean only one request is sent?

Comment: Ajax is always aysnc, but you can do is abort the previous request and initiate other. For reference you can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244341/abort-previous-ajax-request-on-new-request

Comment: @nem035 yes just on request is sent at a time. For example if the user click on button1 and button2, my magical function should wait the answer for button1 before processing the ajax call for button2.

Comment: @Sumit You can run multiple async function synchronously. The thing is my array has not a fixed length or items, it changes over time.

Answer (score 0):

please review this one:

## note:

if user click multiple buttons. function will execute the first one. and Put another events in array (queue). when the **first event finished**, it will **execute next event** from queue.

```js
var btns = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('button')),
    isProcessing = false, queue = [];

function proceed(e){
    if(isProcessing) {
      queue.push(e.target);
      return;
    }
  //start proccesing
  isProcessing = true;
  var ajax = setTimeout(()=> { 
    e.target.classList.add('done');
    isProcessing = false;  
    //processing the queue
    if(queue.length) {
      queue.shift().click();
    }
  },4000);
}

btns.forEach(function(btn){
  btn.addEventListener('click', proceed);
})
```

```css
button.done {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<button>button 1</button>
<button>button 2</button>
<button>button 3</button>
<button>button 4</button>
```