# Depending on how fast you type, onkeyup triggers multiple times

Tags: javascript

I'm encountering a very strange issue with an `onkeyup` function. Depending how fast the person types, the function that is triggered by typing may run multiple times.

```
var inputFilter = document.getElementById('inputFilter');
inputFilter.onkeyup = function(e, value) {
e.preventDefault();
 value = e.target.value
   if (value.length >= 3) {
     console.log(value);
      getItems(value);
   }
};
```

If I type slowly, the `getItems()` function runs perfectly, but if I type really fast it behaves strangely. The `getItems()` function pulls data from a SharePoint list using Ajax(`XMLHttpRequest()`), and creates a table with the results. If I type slowly, the table is just fine, but if I type fast, each table row duplicates. I added to the getItems() function a `body.innerHTML = ''` to make sure it empties the table's body with each run of of the function:

```
 const table = document.getElementById('smeTable'),
 body = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
 body.innerHTML = '';
```

I'm not a programmer, and probably will get many down votes for this probably silly question, but I'm puzzled by this issue. Any ideas would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried onkeypress?

Comment: You need either a faster server and connection, or you've to wait until user stops writing, and then make the trip to the server.

Comment: It is more likely that there is a problem with the `getItems` function then that a listener's callback function is triggered multiple times for the same event.

Comment: It's always a good idea to implement `debounce/throttle` method for keyup events if it does an http call each time.

Comment: Thanks all for the help. Implementing `debounce/throttle` was the right approach. I'll post the solution once I'm allowed to answer my own question, which I think is a couple of days. Although I see that was questioned was marked `duplicate`. Not sure how that will affect people from seeing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

That probably happens because you are producing a lot of ajax requests in a short period of time and since the responses are async, response to the previous keyUp events might load after the response from current keyup and it might mess things up, especially if you are pulling some autocomplete results.

What I would usually do is abore previous ajax request when creating a new request. You can follow an answer from here on how to abort the previous request:
[Abort previous ajax request on new request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244341/abort-previous-ajax-request-on-new-request)

```
 var currentRequest = null;    

currentRequest = jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'value=' + text,
    url: 'AJAX_URL',
    beforeSend : function()    {           
        if(currentRequest != null) {
            currentRequest.abort();
        }
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // Success
    },
    error:function(e){
      // Error
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but we are not allowed to use jQuery. It is pure JavaScript or nothing. :(

Comment: You're welcome. In such case you can do the same with pure js using `XMLHttpRequest.abort()`