# Pause an XMLHttpRequest and resume later

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to pause an `XMLHttpRequest` and resume it later. 
Is it possible to pause an `XMLHttpRequest` and resume it later?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pause a download with XMLHttpRequest in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294012/pause-a-download-with-xmlhttprequest-in-javascript)

Comment: I am trying to implement pause/resume with XmlHttpRequest using abort but after abort i can't get the partially downloaded blob data in xhr.onabort event.

Comment: See the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294012/pause-a-download-with-xmlhttprequest-in-javascript/74098768#74098768