# How to cancel file being uploaded to Amazon S3?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, amazon-s3, paperclip

I added an ability to upload files from Dropbox to my site via Dropbox Chooser.
Everything works fine except one thing - I don't know how to implement `Cancel` functionality correctly. It should work this way - when you click `Cancel` - corresponding file panel should be removed from UI and uploading from Dropbox should stop.

When user clicks `Choose from Dropbox` and selects file and click `Submit` I initiate an `Ajax` request to Rails, to a method `add_file_via_dropbox`. In this method I get an `URL` for Dropbox file to be uploaded to `Amazon S3` server via a help of `Paperclip` gem.

When user clicks `Cancel` I want to get rid of partly-uploaded to `S3` file, which will be stored (upon successful uploading) in `content.attachment` attribute. But when he clicks `Cancel` - a file is still uploading (otherwise he won't see `Cancel` link) and I don't know how to delete it right away.

My other thought is that I can simply add `cancelled` attribute to `content` and then don't display any `content` where such attribute == `true`. But this approach won't save me from wasting space on `Amazon S3` so I should run some background tasks one time per day to delete `cancelled` attachments. 
I would prefer not to save them on `S3` in first place. Is it possible? I thought about moving controller's action `add_file_via_dropbox` to background job so I can `kill` it as soon as I receive `cancel` ajax request from a client. I am a bit confused about all of this. How would you solve this problem? Thanks.

[image: http://i61.tinypic.com/am9p8n.png]

**product_form.html.erb**

```
$.ajax({

  // Cancel file uploading on client side via jqXHR.abort()
  // It's quite useless because with 99% probability that request     
  // already was sent to Rails and is processing by appropriate action

  beforeSend: function(jqXHR, options) {
    tmpl.find('a').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      jqXHR.abort();
      $(this).parents('li').remove();
    });
  },
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "<%= add_file_via_dropbox_url %>",
  data: { product_id: $("#fileupload").data("product_id"), file: dropbox_file },
})

// When Rails response is returned - update UI with "successful upload state"
.done(function(json_file) {
  var done_tmpl = $(tmpl("template-download", json_file));
  var li = $(".files_list").find('[data-uuid="' + json_file.uuid + '"]');
  li.replaceWith(done_tmpl);
}
})
```

**product_controller.rb**

```
# This method is called by Ajax request
def add_file_via_dropbox
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])

  # Each Product has_many Contents(files)
  file = params[:file]
  content = product.contents.build
  content.attachment_remote_url = file[:url]
  content.save

  # Construct json response object for Ajax call
  json_obj = []
  json_obj << {name: content.attachment_file_name,
               size: content.attachment_file_size,
               url: content.attachment.url,
               thumbnailUrl: content.attachment.url,
               deleteUrl: "#{root_url}profile/products/delete_content/#{product.id}/#{content.id}",
               deleteType: "DELETE",
               uuid: file[:uuid]}

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: json_obj }
  end
end
```

**content.rb**

```
class Content
  attr_reader :attachment_remote_url
  has_attached_file :attachment, bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']

  def attachment_remote_url=(url_value)
    self.attachment = URI.parse(url_value)
  end
end
```

**ADDED LATER**

I investigated in more details how Paperclip works:

1) When this line of code executes

```
content.attachment_remote_url = file[:url]
```

This paperclip code executes from `paperclip/.../uri_adapter.rb`
Which downloads file from given URL (Dropbox URL in my example) and save it locally (in temp file in Rails server)

```
class UriAdapter < AbstractAdapter
  def initialize(target)
    @target = target
    @content = download_content # <----
    cache_current_values
    @tempfile = copy_to_tempfile(@content)
  end

...

def download_content
  open(@target) # method from 'open-uri' library
end
```

2) This file will be pushed to S3 only when I save my Model here:

```
content.attachment_remote_url = file[:url]
content.save # <----
```

Paperclip `save` method will be invoked: (`paperclip/.../attachment.rb`)

```
def save
  flush_deletes unless @options[:keep_old_files]
  flush_writes # <-----
  @dirty = false
  true
end
```

And `flush_writes` then pushes local file to S3 (`paperclip/.../s3.rb`)

```
def flush_writes    
  # omitted code       
  s3_object(style).write(file, write_options) # method from `aws-sdk` gem
  # omitted code                 
  end
```

Therefore I narrow my original question to these two:

1) How to cancel call to `open(@target)` when it's already in action (file is downloading to my Rails server)

2) How to cancel call to `s3_object(style).write(file, write_options)` when file is uploading from my Rails server to S3?

Comment: Not tried `Rails`, nor `Amazon S3` . Is `done_tmpl` an `html` `element` ? Or, content within an `html` `element` ? Thanks for sharing

Comment: tmpl("template-download") will expand into an HTML block of code.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551175/how-to-cancel-abort-jquery-ajax-request http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxTransport/ Hope this help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file is still uploading to your server before server-side processes the file to S3, you'll want to abort the connection like you have already.  I.e. [How to cancel/abort jQuery AJAX request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551175/how-to-cancel-abort-jquery-ajax-request)

If the file has uploaded to the server and is now uploading to S3: Because ruby is not async based, you're essentially going to have to let the file upload, but because the server is now uploading it, your client can technically leave the page.  So: I'd pass a unique ID back when your server receives the file, if the user still clicks cancel, then shoot the ID back in and have your server poll or i.e. cron for file to delete.

Comment: I don't want to allow Rails server to completely upload file to S3 because file can be quite big (up to 1Gb) and it will cost me traffic and money. If user clicks "Cancel" while file is uploading it is clear that user don't need it anymore and I would like to Cancel file uploading immediately. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: @yaru One potential way is to spawn a process with the command + arg I.e. in PHP I would do "php 'file-upload-id'".  Then run something with cron every one minute to find any delete requests in a DB, then do a process look up / kill the pid.

Comment: MKN Web Solutions, please read ADDED LATER section (just added it) in my question. Is spawning a process will be still an only acceptable solution for my problem?

Comment: @yaru I just realized you mentioned about uploading a 1GB file, you have to remember that the user uploads to your server, then the server uploads to S3.  It's not a direct upstream to S3 the way you've designed your application.  So technically assuming uploading takes 15-20min for 1GB, if a user cancels during it will correctly cancel the upstream to your server, thereafter the user will think the file is already uploaded (while it is streaming to S3). If a user wanted to cancel the upload, he would have done it within that 15-20min time frame. I think you're overcomplicating the situation.

Comment: MKN Web Solutions, you wrote that "if a user cancels during it will correctly cancel the upstream to your server" but this IS a problem - I don't know how to correctly cancel upstream to my server. Upstream goes not from client itself (I would cancel it via Ajax abort() method). Instead my Rails server itself downloading file specified by user's provided URL to his Dropbox remote file. (see method download_content from Paperclip in my original question). I need to Cancel in 2 situations: 1) file downloading from Dropbox to Rails server; 2) file uploading from Rails server to Amazon S3.