# Stop ajax function on failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm running a long polling ajax that returns status of request. If failed, I need the ajax to stop. The ajax is written like this:

```
function someFunction(url){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data){
            if(data.status == 'FAILED'){
                //Need this ajax to stop
            }
        }
    });
}



$('some-button').on('click',function(
    var url = 'server-url';
    someFunction(url);
));
```

I have to use the `someFunction()` function as this long polling method is being used by multiple other parts of the code. What should I be doing to stop this function?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551175/how-to-cancel-abort-jquery-ajax-request

Comment: Stop how, by the time data is returned, it's done ?

Comment: @AnantDabhi - how would that work exactly, by the time it's  failed or successful, it's a little late to start aborting the call, as it's already complete ?

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` returns a wrapped `xhr` object. Simply use:

```
var req = $.ajax...
..
req.abort()
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
     function someFunction(url){
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function(data){
                if(data.status != 'FAILED'){
                    //Need this ajax to stop
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

your ajax request is already completed in success. but if status is failed and you want to stop further execution of code than you can use not `!`

Answer (score 0):

```
var ajaxReq = null;
ajaxReq = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data){
            if(data.status == 'FAILED'){
                //Need this ajax to stop                     
            }
        }
        error: function (x, y, z) {
            ajaxReq.abort();
       }
    });
```

And you can use ajaxReq.abort() to stop ajax call.

Comment: You are writing the `abort` call in the `success` handler, which means the ajax request has already completed, isn't it. What would calling `abort` do?

Comment: @web-nomad, exactly the problem I faced while trying this solution. I don't think this is the correct solution.