# Detecting client-aborting request Jersey

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, tomcat7, jersey-2.0

I have Jersey providing a restfull web service. It happens often that the client aborts request done via ajax, with the ajax abort methods like is explained here [abort ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551175/how-to-cancel-abort-jquery-ajax-request)

On server side I get the following output. Which is not nice to see. Is there a way to detect an aborted request in Jersey?

```
SEVERE: An I/O error has occurred while writing a response message entity to the container output stream.
org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.MappableException: ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:571)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:378)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:368)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:319)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:364)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.flush(CommittingOutputStream.java:292)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.close(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1086)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.writeTo(ProviderBase.java:544)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:263)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:88)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:215)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.flush(InternalOutputBuffer.java:119)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:793)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:359)
    ... 48 more
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39006980/142446

Answer (score 4):

Aborted request must be logged in tomcat access log. You can find all requests and related response codes in it.

But your problem may be related with system limits. In jersey,for each request to server, I/O container sends new instance of the response writer
so you should check operation system limit which is located **etc/security/limits.conf**.
Mentioned file contains **domain, type and value** fields.

Domain can be an user name, a group name or any wildcard.
type filed can have two values, (soft or hard),
**soft** for enforcing the soft limits, **hard** for enforcing hard limits.
value field is defined limit for domain :)
I think if you increase limit for tomcat user, the problem will be solved.

> **sample conf for tomcat**
>
> tomcat          soft    nofile      102400
>
> tomcat          hard    nofile      102400
>
> tomcat          soft    nproc       102400
>
> tomcat          hard    nproc       102400

Comment: So, I can NOT detect the client aborting a request? this is what you are saying…?

Comment: The problem is related your tomcat based **configuration** . When your server under **heavy load**, operating system can not create and allocate any processes/files to tomcat. And jersey throws mentioned exception, to overcome this problem you should increase these settings in server side. This configuration file is located at **etc/security/limits.conf** in your server.

Comment: But you didn't answer the question how can I disable the log to Tomcat ... I have the same problem, the jersey log the exception in tomcat when the user abort the request, and I want to disable this log, because my client can abort his requests, and it is OK by me.
So... How can I detecting the client aborting request in Jersey and disable the log to tomcat...

Comment: The problem is not about disabling the log to tomact, once you can  intercept such event you can avoid it to be written in the log. I would like to be able to stop completely the processing job that is going on while the caller aborted the request: this allows to save some computation, which may turn into more resources to be used by other clients..

Comment: @LMG So... can you answer this question ???
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494699/detecting-client-aborting-request-jersey-continue