# ClientAbortException when using Jersey 2.13

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

I'm using Jersey 2.13 in my web application for retrieving data async. There are some cases where requests take some time (i.E. when executing complex reports) until their response returns to the client.

When the client does not wait for the async response (leaves the page, closes the browser, etc.), a ClientAbortException is thrown. This behaviour is as expected but it is flooding my log files with stack traces because every single async request that gets canceled before the response returns, prints a stack trace.

The stack trace looks like this:

```
Oct 15, 2014 2:25:23 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder writeResponse
SEVERE: An I/O error has occurred while writing a response message entity to the container output stream.
org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.MappableException: ClientAbortException:  java.io.IOException
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:91)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1154)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:621)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:377)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:367)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:274)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1030)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2441)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: ClientAbortException:  java.io.IOException
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:413)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:366)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:438)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:426)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:91)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter$NonCloseableOutputStreamWrapper.write(ResponseWriter.java:298)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:229)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableOutputStream.write(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:299)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1862)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.close(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1087)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.writeTo(ProviderBase.java:637)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:106)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:85)
                ... 38 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:205)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.access$100(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:37)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:235)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:117)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:192)
                at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:517)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:408)
                ... 55 more
```

I'm also using the Jersey ExceptionMapper to map several Exceptions but this does neither work for

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.MappableException
```

nor for

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException
```

Is there any way to catch this Exception and prevent printing the whole stack trace?

EDIT:

Still looking for an answer...

Comment: I'm also very interested in this. Not only do I get a Jersey stacktrace, but it throws it to the Container(tomcat) and I get a container stacktrace

Comment: I can try help you. Can you share the endpoint code / client code in order to reproduice the bug. Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After digging into the Jersey Coding I found out the the only way to archive this is by disabling the Jersey internal Logger. This can be done in the Class that extends ResourceConfig.

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class Application extends ResourceConfig {

    private final static Logger ORG_GLASSFISH_JERSEY_LOGGER = Logger
            .getLogger("org.glassfish.jersey");
    static {
        ORG_GLASSFISH_JERSEY_LOGGER.setLevel(Level.OFF);
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed, turning off the internal Jersey logger seems like a horrible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this issue by adding a low priority `WriterInterceptor` that detects and ignores exceptions thrown while writing responses.  If you're running on Tomcat and don't mind a dependency on Tomcat classes, you could use `org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException` rather calling `setOutputStream`, which would remove the need for the two nested classes (and the dependency on `org.apache.commons.io.output.ProxyOutputStream`, which could easily also be avoided with a custom `OutputStream` subclass instead).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.WriterInterceptor;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.WriterInterceptorContext;

import org.apache.commons.io.output.ProxyOutputStream;

/**
 * Ignore exceptions when writing a response, which almost always means the
 * client disconnected before reading the full response.
 */
@Provider
@Priority(1)
public class ClientAbortExceptionWriterInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {
    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) throws IOException {
        context.setOutputStream(new ClientAbortExceptionOutputStream(context.getOutputStream()));
        try {
            context.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            for (Throwable cause = t; cause != null; cause = cause.getCause()) {
                if (cause instanceof ClientAbortException) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            throw t;
        }
    }

    private static class ClientAbortExceptionOutputStream extends ProxyOutputStream {
        public ClientAbortExceptionOutputStream(OutputStream out) {
            super(out);
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleIOException(IOException e) throws IOException {
            throw new ClientAbortException(e);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static class ClientAbortException extends IOException {
        public ClientAbortException(IOException e) {
            super(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this as well and finally found a guide to "solve" this.

https://tutorial-academy.com/jersey-workaround-clientabortexception-ioexception/

There are two options where the first is the one that is currently the accepted answer. The other, preferred way, is to add a WriterInterceptor to drop the ClientAbortException. My personal twist is to WARN log this occurrence instead.

In case the URL is unreachable I add my implementation here. **Don't forget to to register it in your Jersey context.**

```
import org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.WriterInterceptor;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.WriterInterceptorContext;
import java.io.IOException;


@Provider
@Priority(1)
public class ClientAbortExceptionWriterInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientAbortExceptionWriterInterceptor.class);

@Override
public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) throws IOException {
    try {
        context.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        for (Throwable cause = t; cause != null; cause = cause.getCause()) {
            if (cause instanceof ClientAbortException) {
                logger.warn("Client aborted request.", cause);
                return;
            }
        }
        throw t;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Chip, it also works putting the code directly in WS.

```
@Path("/myWS")
public class MyWS {   

    private final static Logger ORG_GLASSFISH_JERSEY_LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("org.glassfish.jersey");
    static {
        ORG_GLASSFISH_JERSEY_LOGGER.setLevel(Level.OFF);
    }    

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/version")
    public String version() {
        return "1.0.25";
    }

}
```