# Detecting client-aborting request Jersey - Continue

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

My question is the same as this question:

[Detecting client-aborting request Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962774/detecting-client-aborting-request-jersey)

But nobody answer the question how can I disable the log to Tomcat... 
Because I currently have less then 50 Reputation :( , I can't add a comment to the question, so I will ask it again, hope someone will answer me here.

I have the same problem, the jersey log the exception in tomcat, and I want to disable this log, because my client can abort his requests, and it is OK by me.

So... How can I detecting the client aborting request in Jersey and disable the log to tomcat...

Comment: Please read my Question, I know it is the same question, but nobody answer it for me... I still need to disable this log to Tomcat...
I have tried to add comment to the question you talk about, but I have less then 50 Reputation :( ... so I can't add comments

Comment: Take a look of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752880/clientabortexception-when-using-jersey-2-13

Comment: Facing the same problem.. But I dont want to disable tomcat log, but to find out the reason