# Stop Ajax Request in jQuery After Change The Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-ui

Consider this code that runs when the page is loaded:

```
if ($('#content-recommendation').length) {
    $.ajax({
    url:'/get_content_recommendation/' + gon.item_id + '.js',
    type:"get"
  });
}
```

And this request take about 15 seconds to complete in development. If I go to another page I have to wait until the Ajax is completed so, how do I cancel that Ajax request?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [abort()](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-abort-method) method to abort the request - but be aware that it will just abort the client side listeners from being executed, the server side processes initialized by the quest will still be running

```
//in a shared scope
var xhr;

//then
if ($('#content-recommendation').length) {
    xhr = $.ajax({
        url: '/get_content_recommendation/' + gon.item_id + '.js',
        type: "get"
    }).always(function () {
        xhr = undefined;
    });
}

//later before moving to the new page
if (xhr && xhr.readyState != 4) {
    xhr.abort();
}
```

[How to cancel/abort jQuery AJAX request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551175/how-to-cancel-abort-jquery-ajax-request)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `abort()` to cancel the current request. Detailed instructions here [How to cancel/abort jQuery AJAX request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551175/how-to-cancel-abort-jquery-ajax-request/4551178#4551178)