# AJAX Call Blocking page loading

Tags: php, ajax, webserver

Let's say that I go the page: "http://example.com/page1.php"

At page1.php an (asynchronous) AJAX call is made to "http://example.com/page1.php?action=getSomethingBig" which takes a long time (60 seconds maybe) to load.

Before the AJAX call is done (maybe I'm tired of waiting), I click a link to go to: "http://example.com/page2.php".

How do I avoid that the browser has to wait for the AJAX call to complete before going to "page2.php"?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery you can use the [ajaxStop()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstop/) function. if you use plain javascript you can use the [stop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551175/how-to-cancel-abort-jquery-ajax-request) function in your XMLhttprequest object

Comment: I don't this this is what I need. The function description says: "Register a handler to be called when all Ajax requests have completed." I don't want to sit and wait for it to complete.