# How to abort laravel(php) execution from javascript (ajax)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I have js code :

```
$('#button').on('click', function(e){
    console.log('start');

    if(xhr != ''){
        console.log('terminate');
        xhr.abort()
    }else{
        console.log('NOT terminate');
    }

    xhr = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: method,
        success: function(json) {
            console.log(json);
        },
    });
    console.log('end');
    return false;
});
```

and server laravel code:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    DB::transaction(function () {
       sleep(10);
       Product::find(1)->increment('user_id');
    });
    return 'test';
}
```

when I double click button output is :

```
start
NOT terminate
end
start
terminate
end
test
```

user_id is initially 1, but after execution it is 3 but I want to be 2. So how to terminate(abort) laravel execution from javascript ?

Comment: 2 clicks = 2 times called event = 2 times executed your ajax, so 2 times incremented = 1+1+1 = 3, change the event instead of click use `dblclick` event.

Comment: @Troyer I am looking for mechanism to terminate php exection from javascript, this above is just plain example where is not explained why I need this....

Comment: There is no way to stop PHP server side execution from JS, you could add more parameters in your ajax to create the conditions on the ajax function controller :)

Comment: Maybe create global variable in js named 'counter' and after first click increment it. Than check `counter == 1 ? setTimeout(() => {<your code>}, 3000) : <regular call>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot terminate php execution from inside javascript, they are asyncronous. Each ajax request start a server side php processing that, usually, return a response. But javascript has no control over the server side php once he has sent the request.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to abort current AJAX petition you have to declare `xhr` variable as global.

[How to cancel/abort jQuery AJAX request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551175/how-to-cancel-abort-jquery-ajax-request)

But if you want to execute 1 AJAX petition on a double click, why don't try to use `dblclick` event?

https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/