# How to wait only for 1 second when Ajax Request is made, but don't cancel the request after wait time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, settimeout

I have a situation where i have to return false if ajax request does not return within 1 second. But process the response after the request has been completed. Using Ajax timeout does not work for me because, it cancels the request after that time. But i want the response even if it takes long time.

Example:

```
function call(){
  ajax.request(...)
     if(does not respond in 1 second)
        immediately return false and wait for response
     else
        return response
}
```

Comment: Did you try `setTimeOut`?

Comment: are you using a promise Ajax library, or are you using a callback when Ajax completes?

Comment: @GarrettMotzner: I am using Callback when Ajax completes.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "return" in this context? when doing async calls, "return" doesn't really make as much sense, because a function that starts an async action returns immediately, and doesn't block waiting for that action to finish.

Comment: Can you include a bit of your callback?

Comment: Check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551175/how-to-cancel-abort-jquery-ajax-request)

Comment: @RasanjanaN: the function i specified in setTimeout is only getting executed after current call stack. But i want it to be executed after 1 second not caring about other code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up a race between your request finishing and your handler for the error. If the request finishes first, set a flag that you check before handling the error:

```
function call(){
  let finished = false;
  function callback(){ 
    finished = true 
    // your callback code goes here
  };
  ajax.request(..., callback) // make sure this is an async request
  function handleTimeout() {
    if (finished) return;
    // your timeout code goes here
  }
  setTimeout(handleTimeout, TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS);
}
```

alternatively to setting a flag, you could [cancel the timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout).

Notice that your `call` function doesn't return anything. Instead, you essentially handle events (either or both the request completing or the timeout expiring).

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. The mistake i made is that i kept async:false which dint do the obvious. :)