# How to abort and cancel XHR pending request in jquery/ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

I am using jquery ajax load() function to refresh DIV content every 5 sec. But, after sometime multiple xhr request pending and slow down the process to freez browser! How to abort those pending request after waiting 5 sec/request. Or any better solution to fix this issue?

```
    $(document).ready(
    var xhr;
    var fn = function() {
        if (xhr && xhr.readyState != 4) {
            xhr.abort();
        }
        xhr = $.ajax({});
    };
    var interval = setInterval(fn, 5000);
);
```

Some developer talking about above mentioned code block but i could not fix my problem with it.
HERE IS MY CODE :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slot1_clicker').on('click', function() {
        $("#slot1").load(" #slot1 ", function() {
            $.getScript("/files/po.js");
        });
    });
});
setInterval(function() {
    $('.slot1_clicker').trigger('click');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: xhr.abort(); => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551175/how-to-cancel-abort-jquery-ajax-request/4551178

Comment: Don't use `setInterval` for things that can potentially run longer than the specified interval. Instead, you should use `setTimeout` to start the task, then call `setTimeout` again inside the task at the very end to queue up the next run.

Comment: `setInterval(function() {
$("#slot1").load(" #slot1 ");
}, 2000 );
setTimeout(function() {
      $("#slot1").load(" #slot1");
}, 2000 );`
You mean i should write like this skip the XHR pending request? or what you meant? Can you please highlight with correct syntax